# git init is creating in incomplete .git folder - how do I fix it?

Tags: git

When I used to run git init, I'd get a .git folder that looked like this:

```
.git
|_config
|_description
|_HEAD
|_hooks/
|_index
|_info/
|_logs/
|_objects/
|_refs/
```

now, git init is producing this:

```
.git
|_HEAD
|_config
|_hooks/
|_index
|_logs/
|_objects/
|_refs/
```

Why isn't it creating `info/` anymore - am I missing something obvious or is something really going wrong? Is there an easy way to fix my git setup so that `git init` works properly/like it used to?

edit:
**git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)** -- I think it's the standard that comes installed on a macbook with mountain lion. No updates were performed in the meantime, the only thing I can think of is eclipse (Juno) picked up a git folder for a project - it could conceivably have modified some settings, but my gitconfig and git_templates look the same.

Comment: More details needed: which platform, which Git version worked, did you upgrade in the meantime, etc.

Comment: Is the lack of that directory actually causing a problem? Or do you just think it *may* be a problem because it’s different than before?

Comment: your template folder might have changed

Comment: The lack of `info/` *is* causing a problem, because that houses the exclude file - I could just recreate that (I think), but I am in general concerned that it and the other missing elements *may* cause problems. Either way I'd like it produced automatically for ease-of-use, which is motivation enough on its own.

Comment: Nevik: ~/.git_templates/ hasn't changed - is there another one I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Do you have any kind of global gitignore in your home directory?  do `ls -a ~/*.git*` please.  Also do the same in the base directory of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue/solution was really simple:

I was expecting my `git init` to pull from both template folders (my `/usr/share/git-core/templates` and the one at `~/.git_templates` referenced in `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` that I set up for myself to add my own hooks). It seems like it will only use one, so I just `cp`'d over the core stuff to my new one and everything works great.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal valid git repo is

```
mkdir -p .git/{objects,refs}
echo ref: refs/heads/master > .git/HEAD
git config core.repositoryformatversion 0
```

Anything past that that you want to be sure of, just add e.g. `mkdir -p .git/info` to your own  ritual.

Comment: but what changed? git init used to automatically create the info directory - it must be possible to automate it again?

Comment: vanilla git installs `.git/info/exclude` in v1.7.12.4 (`checkout v1.7.12.4; cd templates;make;find -name info` and it's there), so somewhere along the way someone with control over the distribution or your installation removed it from the template.  `git help init` will show you how to control it.

Answer (score 1):

In my git installation (Debian package, version 1.8.1.1), `git init` will create the directory `.git/info`, but only if it is included in `/usr/share/git-core/templates/`. This is the templating mechanism described in the manpage of git init (section "TEMPLATE DIRECTORY").

So check whether the `info` directory is included in your template directory (which may be in multiple places, check the manpage).

As to why it is no longer automatically created: That seems to be caused by your git installation or by your personal config. Git from the official git repository will create this directory.

Comment: my `/usr/share/git-core/templates/` has `info/exclude` though. 
(as well as `branches/`, `description`, and `hooks/`)

my git man page also doesn't mention "template" anywhere.

I can't think of anything that would've changed the global configuration, and I've checked that none of my personal configurations have changed. Any idea why git might be ignoring the templates?

Comment: @WFW: You looked at the wrong man page - you need "man git-init". If that does not help you, you'll probably have to debug the problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. The template section lists this, though:
"The template directory used will (in order):
(1)The argument given with the `--template` option.

(2)The contents of the `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable.

(3)The `init.templatedir` configuration variable.

(4)The default template directory: `/usr/share/git-core/templates.`

So what happened to the last one? Why is it getting ignored and how can I restore it? Is there a configuration file where it's listed that a program like eclipse could have edited?

Comment: @WFW: Sorry, no idea. I don't know anything beyond what the man page says. If git does not act as described in the man page, that looks like a bug in git (or your installation). I'm afraid you'll have to debug it yourself.

Comment: I'm just re-init-ing all of my git repos as I go now using `--template=/usr/share/git-core/templates` which is working. Any thoughts on if this could possibly be related to permissions? I've tried to find out what `/usr/share/git-core/templates` is supposed to be set to, but can't find it - any ideas?